# Не получается поставить заголовок QSqlTableModel в pyqt6

Tags: python, pyqt

Пытаюсь воспользоваться Model/View архитектурой для работы с базой данных. Пересмотрел всю документацию, никаких аномалий, у всех работает Qt.Horizontal/Vertical. Выдает ошибку при запуске: AttributeError: type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'Horizontal'. Вот кусок кода. Пожалуйста, помогите.

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QMessageBox,
    QTableView,
    QWidget
)
import sys
from ticketapp import Ui_MainWindow


class mywindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.reset_click)

        con = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        con.setDatabaseName('data.db')
        try: con.open()
        except: sys.exit(1)

        self.modelB = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.modelB.setTable("Book")
        self.modelB.EditStrategy.OnFieldChange
        self.modelB.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Пользователь")
        self.modelB.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Выступление")
        self.modelB.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Ряд")
        self.modelB.setHeaderData(3, Qt.Horizontal, "Место")
        self.modelB.select()
```

Comment: `Qt.Orientation.Horizontal`   ?

Comment: @S.Nick Благодарю! Действительно так работает.